# Two identical queries that give different results

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have 2 queries: one is written in ANSI SQL, another is written using oracle dialect.
I think that they both must give the same resultset, but it is no true. First query gives 385 rows and the second - only 25

First:

```
SELECT  idclient, cl.surname, sum(sub1.s) 
    FROM client cl JOIN incomestatement incst USING(idclient)
                   JOIN (SELECT c.idincome ID, sum(inst.total) AS s  
                         FROM instalment inst JOIN credit c  USING(idcredit)
                         WHERE inst.paydate > c.paydate AND c.isloaned = 1
                         GROUP BY c.idincome) sub1 ON incst.idincome = sub1.ID
   GROUP BY idclient, cl.surname;
```

Second:

```
SELECT  c.idclient, c.surname, sum(sub.s)
FROM client c, incomestatement inc,
      (SELECT sum(inst.total) as s, cr.idincome as id
       FROM instalment inst, credit cr
       WHERE inst.paydate > cr.paydate AND cr.isloaned = 1 AND cr.idcredit = inst.idcredit
       GROUP BY cr.idincome
       ) sub
WHERE c.idclient = inc.idclient AND inc.income = sub.ID
group by c.idclient, c.surname;
```

So why they don't give the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach the problem in steps.

1. Do the two sub-queries produce the same data sets?

   - If they do, proceed to step 2.
   - If not, then you have two simpler queries to analyze and dissect.
2. Given that the pair of sub-queries produce the same answer, you can then establish whether the Client and IncomeStatement joins give the same results (treat it as another sub-query)

   - If they do, proceed to step 3.
   - If not, then you have a pair of queries (one with JOIN, one with classic SQL notation) to analyze and dissect.
3. Given that the pair of joins and the pair of subqueries each produce the same result, analyze why the join of these does not work correctly.

Comment: yes, two sub-queries produce the same dataset and the Client and IncomeStatement join(like: select idclient from client join incomestatement using(idclient)) in both notation produce the same dataset. These queries even have identical plans. But I don't know why they give different datasets

Comment: thanks, i've solved this problem. I have mistaked in second query here inc.income = sub.ID . Instead of this I have to write  inc.idincome = sub.ID because idincome is the primary key

Comment: That's very odd...the only other decomposition step is to write the outermost queries without the GROUP BY and SUM (you just select the 'sub.s' or 'sub1.s' values.  These too should be the same given what you've said so far, but that's the only other thing I can see to check.  **Oh**, you solved it...good!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made a commit?
It's possible that you don´t commited some transactions, so the results can be differents.

Comment: no, the problem isn't in commit. I have run these queries after starting database.